# Baby begins crying forcefully when Fed, extremely irritated when held, but calms down when put down

Tags: infant, crying, bottle-feeding

We've recently experienced a new phenomena with our almost-6 month old, and nothing I see online explains it.

Sometimes, usually when he has just woken up from a nap, we will try to feed our baby, and he will immediately begin crying and pushing the bottle away forcefully, then afterwards begin arching his back and rolling away from us, and will continue this until put down on his back, at which point he will slowly but surely calm down.

Now, I have noticed that he seems to have a gurgling cough when this happens - as if bubbles or phlegm are trapped in his throat, and sometimes if I can hold him in the right position, patting his back will also help him calm down.

But, even after this he still does not want to eat, and will still act very fussy when picked up, then calm down when put down.

I do not know what is happening - can anyone give me some advice on what might be going on, and how we can help my son with this?

Comment: Since this is a sudden and distressing change to an important behavor (feeding), have you consulted with your pediatrician?

Comment: @WayneConrad Not yet, but it may be our next step.

Comment: What happens if you give him some transition time after sleeping, before feeding? For example go for a walk, have some play time? / What happens if you pop baby into the high chair to have some sensory fun before offering the bottle?  E.g. peas are fun to play with.  The bottle could be offered after small servings of solids. / I think it's rather important with children of all ages to learn to follow the child's lead.  Often the more you push, the more the child resists.  *Distraction is often an effective tool!*

Comment: Six months old is VERY different from two or three months old.  Are you perhaps a little out of sync with each other?

Comment: @aparente001 Possibly - we just had a visit from a wellness checkup group, and they suggested we try putting oat cereal in his formula, or that he might be less hungry less frequently than we think.  So we're going to try adjusting our routine a litte.

Comment: Sounds encouraging!  I hope you'll post an update in the form of an answer, or by editing your question if it doesn't go as well as hoped, after you've had a chance to see how the experiment goes.

Comment: Two new ideas, maybe baby gets overheated when held, and maybe there's some sensory avoidance or allergy to, e.g., the laundry detergent/soap you're using. Or maybe there's some sensory seeking causing baby to get bored and irritated by the holding.  Some babies aren't big snugglers.  If there are laundry-related sensitivities, you can give an extra rinse with Calgon to soften the water (helps get all the soap out), and ensure you're using soap for sensitive skin (e.g. Dreft or something from a health food store) and ensure your laundry products are unscented.  Family can go unscented too.